# React userSelector gives undefined value for the first time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, axios

Im fetching data from api using axios, in the api `https:/...?vs_currency=${currency}&...` I am trying to assign `currency` value to api using redux. The problem is useSelector gives the `undefined` value for the first time and i failed to fetch data from this api. But then useSelector works fine. Error display is `https:/...?vs_currency=undefined&...`

Here is the redux code

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const currencySlice = createSlice({
  name: "currency",
  initialState: {
    currency: "usd", // first i have currency: null. but then i change it to avoid undefined value, but same result
  },
  reducers: {
    selectCurrencyAndSymbol: (state, action) => {
      state.currency = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { selectCurrencyAndSymbol } = currencySlice.actions;
export const selectcurrency = (state) => state.currency.currency;
export default currencySlice.reducer;
```

Here is the useSelector code

```js
importing stuff ...

function Carousel() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [trending, setTrending] = useState("");
  const currencySelector = useSelector(selectcurrency);

  const fetchTrendingCoins = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get(TrendingCoins(currencySelector?.currency));
    setTrending(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrendingCoins();
  }, [currencySelector.currency]);
  
  ...
```

I Also try to directly assign value for the first time

```js
  
    var currencyValue;
    
   useEffect(() => {
    
      currencyValue = !currencySelector.currency
       ? currencyValue === "pkr"
       : currencyValue === "usd";

    currencyValue = currencySelector?.currency;
    
    fetchTrendingCoins();
    }, [currencyValue]);
```

Here is the useDispatch code

```js
importing stuff ...

function Header() {
  const [currency, setCurrency] = useState("usd");
  const [symbol, setsymbol] = useState("$");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currency === "pkr") setsymbol("Rs");
    else if (currency === "usd") setsymbol("$");

    dispatch(selectCurrencyAndSymbol({ currency, symbol }));
  }, [currency]);

  ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Here you can see that your sending in an 
object {
currency: "usd", 
symbol: "$"
}
selectCurrencyAndSymbol({currency, symbol})
```

Then in your useEffect you will have issues with the way your using setState

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (currency === "pkr") setsymbol("Rs");
   //else if (currency === "usd") setsymbol("$");
   //here symbol will be $ as the state wouldnt have updated yet by the 
   //time the dispatch is envoked
    dispatch(selectCurrencyAndSymbol({ currency, symbol }));
  }, [currency]);
```

Your first soloution is to add symbol to your dependancy array which will cause the useEffect to be run when the symbol is updated

Second solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
 let symbol = "";
    if (currency === "pkr") symbol = "Rs";
     else if (currency === "usd") symbol = "$"
    dispatch(selectCurrencyAndSymbol({ currency, symbol }));
  }, [currency]);
```

Then finally in your store state you have

```
initialState: {
//NOTE: This is not an object at first
    currency: "usd",
  },
reducers: {
selectCurrencyAndSymbol: (state, action) => {
//Here for example the action payload is {currency: "usd", symbol: "$"} 
  state.currency = action.payload;
},
```

Your solution would be if you want to keep the object approach:

```
initialState: {
        currency: { currency: "usd", symbol: "$" };
      },
    reducers: {
    selectCurrencyAndSymbol: (state, action) => {
      state.currency = action.payload;
    Or
      state.currency.currency = action.payload.currency
      state.currency.symbol = action.payload.symbol
    },
```

OR

```
initialState: {
             currency: "usd", 
             symbol: "$"
          },
 reducers: {
        selectCurrencyAndSymbol: (state, action) => {
          state.currency = action.payload.currency
          state.symbol = action.payload.currency
        },
```

However if you want to keep it as

```
initialState: {
        currency: "usd"
      },
//Then just send through the currency in your func like this 
selectCurrencyAndSymbol(currency)
```

Please note then when you use your selector to get the state how you access the data is dependant on how it is defined so for example
//Also just a heads up best practice is to use cam case here for selectcurrency should be selectCurrency

```
export const selectCurrency = (state) => state.currency.currency;
```

how we get the data could be const data = useSelector(selectCurrency)
either data.currency if we followed the object approach other wise just data will work

I hope this gives you some insight

Comment: Thanks man, i fix the store state and make objects of currency (key value), and code run.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the redux store with redux dev tool or console log. Can you see the currency value?

If currency might be null or undefined. Can't you put a if statement before fetchTrendingCoins function in useEffect? If there is no currency don't fetch.

Comment: Yes i check the values in redux tool and through console log. And i told in question that i use ternary operator for checking values, whether they are null, undefined or not